# Atom won't open

Tags: atom-editor

I just install Atom, all is fine but when it finished It doesn't open.
I used the command

```
atom --safe
```

I have this error:

```
user/share/atom/atom: error while loading shared libraries: libXss.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[known issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/13176)

```
Workaround listed as

$ pkcon install libXScrnSaver
```

Comment: thanks it works, but i have  now another error: Home diracory not accessible: permission denied

Comment: do you have to prefix the above with sudo?